# Make Perl web server deliver an ogg through HTTP to Chrome for a HTML5 audio element

Tags: perl, google-chrome, http-headers, webserver, html5-audio

I am writing a Perl script that acts as a simple web server that serves audio files over HTML5. I have succeeded in getting it to show a page to a web browser with an HTML5 audio element. It continues to listen to the socket for when the browser asks for an audio file via a GET request; hh.ogg in this example and tries to respond with the ogg inside the message body. It works over port 8888.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;

my $port = 8888;
my $server = new IO::Socket::INET(  Proto => 'tcp',
                                    LocalPort => $port,
                                    Listen => SOMAXCONN,
                                    ReuseAddr => 1)
            or die "Unable to create server socket";

# Server loop
while(my $client = $server->accept())
{
    my $client_info;
    my $faviconRequest = 0;
    while(<$client>)
    {
        last if /^\r\n$/;
        $faviconRequest = 1 if ($_ =~ m/favicon/is);
        print "\n$_" if ($_ =~ m/GET/is);
        $client_info .= $_;
    }

    if ($faviconRequest == 1)
    {
        #Ignore favicon requests for now
        print "Favicon request, ignoring and closing client";
        close($client);
    }
    incoming($client, $client_info) if ($faviconRequest == 0);
}

sub incoming
{
    print "\n=== Incoming Request:\n";
    my $client = shift;
    print $client &buildResponse($client, shift);
    print "Closing \$client";
    close($client);
}

sub buildResponse
{
    my $client = shift;
    my $client_info = shift;
    my $re1='.*?';
    my $re2='(hh\\.ogg)';
    my $re=$re1.$re2;

    print "client info is $client_info";

    # Send the file over socket if it's the ogg the browser wants.
    return sendFile($client) if ($client_info =~ m/$re/is);

    my $r = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Hello!</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            Hello World.
            <audio src=\"hh.ogg\" controls=\"controls\" preload=\"none\"></audio>
            </body>
            </html>";
    return $r;
}

sub sendFile
{
    print "\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> sendFile";
    my $client = shift;
    open my $fh, '<' , 'hh.ogg';
    my $size = -s $fh;
    print "\nsize: $size";

    print $client "Allow: GET\015\012";
    print $client "Accept-Ranges: none\015\012";
    print $client "Content-Type: \"audio/ogg\"\015\012";
    print $client "Content-Length: $size\015\012";
    print "\nsent headers before sending file";

    ############################################
    #Take the filehandle and send it over the socket.
    my $scalar = do {local $/; <$fh>};
    my $offset = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        print "\nsyswriting to socket. Offset: $offset";
        $offset += syswrite($client, $scalar, $size, $offset);
        last if ($offset >= $size);
    }
    print "Finished writing to socket.";
    close $fh;
    return "";
}
```

The sendFile subroutine is called when the GET request matches a regex for hh.ogg.
I send a few headers in the response before writing the ogg to the socket before closing.
This code works exactly as I'd expect in Firefox. When I press play the script receives a GET from Firefox asking for the ogg, I send it over and Firefox plays the track.

My problem is the script crashes in Google Chrome. Chrome's developer tools just says it cannot retrieve hh.ogg. When I visit 127.0.0.1:8888 in my browser while the script is running I can download hh.ogg. I have noticed that Chrome will make multiple GET requests for hh.ogg whereas Firefox just makes one. I've read that it may do this for caching reasons? This could be a reason as to why the script crashes.

I have

```
print $client "Accept-Ranges: none\015\012";
```

to try and stop this behaviour but it didn't work.

I'm not sure of exactly what headers to respond to Chrome to let it receive the file within one HTTP response. When the script crashes I also occasionally get this message printed out from Perl; otherwise there are no other errors. It will quit somewhere inside the while loop where I syswrite() to the socket.

```
Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at ./test.pl line 91, <$fh> line 1.
```

Which is referring to this line.

```
$offset += syswrite($client, $scalar, $size, $offset);
```

I don't know why there would be any uninitialized values.

Would anyone have any ideas why this could be happening? If at all possible I'd like to accomplish this without requiring additional modules from CPAN.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [real web server](http://plackperl.org) instead that is already working and thorougly debugged instead of messing with sockets yourself. The Web is always more complicated than you think. Run the following app with [`plackup --port=8888`](http://p3rl.org/plackup).

```
use HTTP::Status qw(HTTP_OK);
use Path::Class qw(file);
use Plack::Request qw();
use Router::Resource qw(router resource GET);

my $app = sub {
    my ($env) = @_;
    my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
    my $router = router {
        resource '/' => sub {
            GET {
                return $req->new_response(
                    HTTP_OK,
                    [Content_Type => 'application/xhtml+xml;charset=UTF-8'],
                    [ '… HTML …' ]  # array of strings or just one big string
                )->finalize;
            };
        };
        resource '/hh.ogg' => sub {
            GET {
                return $req->new_response(
                    HTTP_OK,
                    [Content_Type => 'audio/vorbis'],
                    file(qw(path to hh.ogg))->resolve->openr # file handle
                )->finalize;
            };
        };
    };
    $router->dispatch($env);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error says `Use of uninitialized value in addition` which means it is not inside the syswrite, but in the += operation. `syswrite()` returns undef if there is an error. Which seems consistent with your overall error with Chrome. The `$!` variable contains some info about the writing error.